# react-native stories-view shows installation error unable to resolve dependency error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

S C:\myReactProject\test_shadi> npm i react-native-stories-view
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: test_shadi@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.11.0" from react-native-stories-view@1.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-stories-view
npm ERR!   react-native-stories-view@"^1.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Sukhendu Gatait\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sukhendu Gatait\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-04-13T05_36_20_264Z-debug.log

my version

"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.0",

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
npm install react-native-stories-view --legacy-peer-deps
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks  it works for me, but for react-native-stories-view it works not properly on click left or right of the image view not changing the image properly ,my code is <StoryContainer
   visible={true}
   enableProgress={true}
   progressIndex={0}
   barStyle={{
   
    barWidth: 100, 
    barHeight: 4
 }}
   images={images}
   duration={20}  
   containerStyle={{
       width: '100%',
       height: '100%',
   }}
/> please help thanks in advance